# Android weird "divide by zero" exception in ListView

Tags: android, listview, arithmetic-expressions

I am using GA to tracking my applications. I have noticed that there is a weird exception reported sometimes on every release. The reported calling stack shows that it seems to be the Android issue of the user's device(I can never reproduce this issue). I tried hard but still cannot find a clue, is there anyone have some experience with this problem?

```
Thread: main, Exception: java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero
 at android.widget.AbsListView$FlingRunnable.run(AbsListView.java:2937)
 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Do you know what version of Android they are running?  You could look up what is on AbsListView.java:2937

Comment: I wish I could, however GA did not report the Android version in crash report.